# stanford core nlp -- "last year" not recognized as a date

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am running Stanford Core NLP locally and comparing the results with the web interface at http://http://corenlp.run/. For the test sentence, "The economy grew by 2% last year", the web interface identifies "last year" as a date entity.
[NER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXSmx.jpg)

But my local instance fails to recognize "last year" as a date:

```
{'after': ' ',
  'before': ' ',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 23,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 27,
  'index': 7,
  'lemma': 'last',
  'ner': **'O'**,
  'originalText': 'Last',
  'pos': 'JJ',
  'word': 'Last'},
 {'after': '',
  'before': ' ',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 28,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 32,
  'index': 8,
  'lemma': 'year',
  'ner': **'O'**,
  'originalText': 'Year',
  'pos': 'NN',
  'word': 'Year'}
```

Strangely, if I change "last year" to "last month", "last month" does get recognized by my local instance as a date.

```
{'after': ' ',
  'before': ' ',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 23,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 27,
  'index': 7,
  'lemma': 'last',
  'ner': **'DATE'**,
  'normalizedNER': 'Last Month ',
  'originalText': 'Last',
  'pos': 'JJ',
  'word': 'Last'},
 {'after': '',
  'before': ' ',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 28,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 33,
  'index': 8,
  'lemma': 'Month',
  'ner': **'DATE'**,
  'normalizedNER': 'Last Month ',
  'originalText': 'Month',
  'pos': 'NNP',
  'word': 'Month'}
```

Help with understanding and resolving this will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the latest code from GitHub with the latest models, and run this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file example-1.txt -outputFormat text
```

On your example, I find "last year" marked as date.  I would presume this is true for 3.8.0 as well.

Comment: The same holds true for the server.

Comment: You are entirely correct, and apologies for the time you spent. I now believe there's a bug in our own Windows service which serves up Stanford CoreNLP.

Comment: Allow me to elaborate on the situation: I am using the C# interface described [here](https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html). If I just reproduce the example given there, "last year" is not recognized as a date.